# How to calculate the Round Robin Waiting Times for Multi-Core CPUs

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, round-robin

I have a question on multi-cores & multi-Cpu RR simulation; I am trying to understand how the WTime is derived for a multi-core and mulit-CPU RoundRobin Simulation Algorithm.
    I am trying to figure out if this assumption is right?

```
#CPU => 2;
#Cores => 2;
#Processes => 6;
TQ = 5;
Process#    BurstTime
1           5
2           6
3           7
4           8
5           9
6           10


Process RR Algorithm Data       
Process#    BTime       WTime   CPU#
1           5           0       1
2           5           0       1
3           5           5       2
4           5           5       2
5           5           10      1
6           5           10      1
2           1           17      2
3           2           17      2
4           3           21      1
5           4           21      1
6           5           26      2
Is the this correct? Specifically P2 WTime?
P1 => 0
P2 => 17 - 0 = 17
P3 => 17 - (5*1) - 0 = 12
P4 => 21 - (5*1) - 0 = 16
P5 => 21 - (5*1) - 0 = 21
P6 => 26 - (5*1) - 0 = 21
```

Calculate the Average Waiting Time for the Process => (0 + 17 + 12 + 16 + 21 + 21) / 6

Comment: Is "burst time" the execution time? Are there 2 cores for each processor, or total?

Comment: Yes Burst time is the execution time and yes there are 2 core in each processor.  What I really want to verify is the total WTime Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have only one global queue, there are 4 cores in total, cores are assigned (if more than one is idle) from 1/1 to 2/2, and the context switch times are 0:

```
Process #  core #  start  end  remaining    acc. waiting time  
1          1/1      0      5    0            0 *          
2          1/2      0      5    1            0       
3          2/1      0      5    2            0                
4          2/2      0      5    3            0
5          1/1      5      10   4            5
6          1/2      5      10   5            5
2          2/1      5      6    0            0=0+0*
3          2/2      5      7    0            0=0+0 * (core became idle)
4          2/1      6      9    0            1=0+1 * (core became idle)
5          1/1      10     14   0            5=5+0 *
6          1/2      10     15   0            5=5+0 *
```

`*` marks the final accumulated waiting time.